# how can I make the 'content' db column to become markdown content to output to jinja?

Tags: python, flask

models.py

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):  # table name: user
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}')"


class Post(db.Model):   # table name: post
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.date_posted}')"
```

main.py

```
@main.route('/')
def index():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=5)

    return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)
```

My question is how can I make the 'content' db column to become markdown content to output to jinja?

Comment: main.py pseudo code to transfer content to markdown format but 'Post'/'Pagination' object is not iterable  

    `posts = []  
    for note in notes:  
        note = dict(note)  
        note['content'] = markdown.markdown(note['content'])  
        posts.append(note)`

Comment: append new information in question - not in comment. It will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it seems you have now new problem - so you should create new question on new page.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Flask Markdown](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Markdown/)

To install:

```sh
pip install flask_markdown
```

[Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Markdown/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but 'Post'/'Pagination' object is not iterable.

Comment: I still do not know how to solve "'Post'/'Pagination' object is not iterable"

Comment: I think you need to read this [example](https://riptutorial.com/flask/example/22202/rendering-pagination-in-jinja). I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you. I will study the example you provided.